# Showing additional information through an onclick/javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, database

Hi I'm using javascript/php/html and at the moment I am displaying information on "Cars" when I click more information it displays "further information" on the same cars and hides the cars tab (all this information is taken from a database).

But right now i'm trying to get it to display this information but for each "car" to have its own "further information" so when I click it, it just shows that cars information beneath it alongside the "car". And when I click another car it hides the previous further information and displays the new one.

Here is how I have done it, but it just displays the link, the link doesn't do anything...

Javascript:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function toggle_visibility(id) {
        var thelist = document.getElementsByClassName("alist");
        for (var i = 0; i < thelist.length; i++) {
            thelist[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        var e = document.getElementById(id);
        if(e.style.display == 'block') {
            e.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            e.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
//]]>  

</script>
</head>
```

PHP:

```
<body>

      <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('list1');">
      <p>Car information</p>
    </a>
    <div id="list1" class="alist" style="display:none;">

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * from Car";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
while ($details = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
    {
        $display = "<p>";
        $display.= $details["carMake"] . "&nbsp;";
        $display.= $details["carModel"];
        $display.="<a href='#' >More information</a>";
        $display.="</p>";
        echo ($display);
    }
?>
        </div>

    <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('list2');">
      <p>More information</p>
    </a>

    <div id="list2" class="alist" style="display:none;">

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * from Car";
$result = mysql_query ($sql);
while ($details = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
    {
        $display = "<p>";
        $display.= $details["carMileage"];
        $display.= $details["carColour"];
        $display.= $details["carMOT"];
        $display.= "</p>";
        echo ($display);
    }
?>
    </div>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code! And why are you performing the same query twice?

Comment: I got rid of the mysql etc from the second part but it will not up anything when the more information link is clicked..

Answer (score 0):

Replace the first part of your function with this:

```
function toggle_visibility(evt, id) {
    var ev = evt || window.event;
    ev.preventDefault();
    ...
};
```

This will keep the link (`<a href="#">`) from trying to load the `#` page (aka the current page).  Also need to change your HTML to use this on that link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(event, 'list1');">
```

Or...you can just make this whole thing easy as hell and use jQuery.